# Convert a RTP sequence payload (coded with GSM\ opus\speex ) in a .wav file

Tags: voip, rtp, codec, speech

I have a text file contaning payload of RTP packets (in hex,coded with GSM\ opus\speex ) belong to a VoIP conversation, does anyone know how to convert this file into a .wav audio file?

I'm using windows.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you need to write some code for that, do you have code already?

Comment: no i have not any code! do you have any one? can you help me?

Comment: any answer??????????????

Answer (score 1):

.wav is just an file container which you can have an any codec format and makes the player to recognize the codec inside. Refer Wiki: WAV and for more technical details refer [WaveFormat](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).  And It just wrappers the raw codec content.  If you have experience in C program, there are open source available to convert one codec to PCM. Since PCM is the raw audio data in 16 bit format.

But I suggest an solution but don't know it will met your requirement.

1. install latest wireshark
2. using wireshark capture the RTP packets.
3. Select UDP packet and Right click and choose Decode As option
4. Select Transport tab and choose RTP protocol
5. Now you can see RTP packet with right codec
6. Go to Telephony -> RTP -> Stream analysis -> Save the RTP Payload as .raw

At this stage the codec data is available in .raw file format.

There are open software are available are available such as [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), ffmpeg etc...

From there are you can covert .raw to .wav format.

After that  you can play in VLC (PCM, GSM, ADPM, Alaw , uLaw) or any other supported player (Amr)
You won't find Speex, g729 since these are paid